# Ruby on Rails - linecache error while trying to ' bundle install '

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, linecache

Hi I'm trying to run **bundle install** on my windows machine it runs fine until it reaches the linecache and then spits out a huge error:

```
Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
Using rake (0.8.7)
Using abstract (1.0.0)
Using activesupport (3.0.3)
Using builder (2.1.2)
Using i18n (0.5.0)
Using activemodel (3.0.3)
Using erubis (2.6.6)
Using rack (1.2.2)
Using rack-mount (0.6.14)
Using rack-test (0.5.7)
Using tzinfo (0.3.26)
Using actionpack (3.0.3)
Using mime-types (1.16)
Using polyglot (0.3.1)
Using treetop (1.4.9)
Using mail (2.2.17)
Using actionmailer (3.0.3)
Using arel (2.0.9)
Using activerecord (3.0.3)
Using activeresource (3.0.3)
Using bundler (1.0.12)
Using thor (0.14.6)
Using railties (3.0.3)
Using rails (3.0.3)
Using render_component_vho (3.0.3)
Using verification (1.0.1)
Using active_scaffold_vho (3.0.19)
Using columnize (0.3.2)
Installing linecache (0.43) with native extensions C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby
/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:533:in `rescue in block in build_extensions': ERROR
: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)

        C:/Ruby192/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
Can't handle 1.9.x yet
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby192/bin/ruby


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/linecache
-0.43 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/linecache-0.43/ext/gem_mak
e.out
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:511:in `b
lock in build_extensions'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:486:in `e
ach'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:486:in `b
uild_extensions'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:159:in `i
nstall'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/sour
ce.rb:96:in `install'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/inst
aller.rb:55:in `block in run'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/spec
_set.rb:12:in `block in each'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/spec
_set.rb:12:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/spec
_set.rb:12:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/inst
aller.rb:44:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/inst
aller.rb:8:in `install'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/cli.
rb:225:in `install'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/vend
or/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/vend
or/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/vend
or/thor.rb:246:in `dispatch'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/vend
or/thor/base.rb:389:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.12/bin/bundle:13:in
 `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby192/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby192/bin/bundle:19:in `<main>'
```

I've tried googling for the problem and found two posts that explain the problem that I have first is a [Stackoveflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026096/receiving-error-on-windows-machine-when-installing-linecache-error-failed-to-bui) which is pretty close to what I've got, but upon further inspection I found that the solution given in that post was not what I needed
another is [this post](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/115061) that seems to discuss the exact problem that I have but doesn't give a solution anyone have any idea what I should do??

**Ruby Version =>** 1.9.2

**Rails Version =>** oh come on it doesn't even tell rails version it just prints out another error

```
Could not find linecache-0.43 in any of the sources
Try running `bundle install`.
```

any ideas what I'm doing wrong?? any help would be immensely appreciated

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You should try installing `linecache19` instead of `linecache`. The gem you are trying to install is incompatible with Ruby version 1.9.2.

This is also suggested by the error message:

```
Can't handle 1.9.x yet
```

Comment: yey, thnks for the suggestion,

Comment: If you are using ruby-debug (has dependency on linecache) with ruby1.9.x (has dependency on linecache19), just the linecache19 is not going to help. You will need to switch ruby-debug to ruby-debug19.

Comment: @ramonrails this is over a year later, but I love you man! thank you so much for posting your comment!

Comment: try "debugger" for even smoother experience and less hassles in bundling

Comment: For Ruby versions > 2, use byebug as [suggested here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30942333/ddg#30944517)

Answer (score 8):

"debugger" gems has worked more flawless for me lately.
I switched from ruby-debug19 to debugger which installs the dependencies without any hassle.

Answer (score 7):

1.9.2-p136 + RVM. Worked using ruby-debug19 which installs linecache19 as a dependency:

gem install ruby-debug19 -- --with-ruby-include=$rvm_path/src/ruby-1.9.2-p136/

Comment: both linechache19 and ruby-debug19 should be installed

Comment: This helped me a fix a problem trying to install offline.  Make was breaking on linecache when trying to retrieve from ftp rubylang, this got around that - thanks!