# intalling linecache-0.46 gem(I am using rbenv)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundle-install, linecache

While bundle install the error:

Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
    /home/launchpad/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby extconf.rb
```

Can't handle 1.9.x yet
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/launchpad/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby

Gem files will remain installed in /home/launchpad/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/linecache-0.46 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/launchpad/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/linecache-0.46/ext/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing linecache (0.46), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install linecache -v '0.46'` succeeds before bundling.

Comment: Could you post your Gemfile?

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing the error "Can't handle 1.9.x yet" because the linecache gem is not compatible with Ruby 1.9.x. It looks like you are using Ruby 1.9.3-p44.

There is another gem called linecache19 that you can try that is compatible with 1.9.x.

Alternatively, you can:

1. Use an older version of Ruby via rbenv
2. Eliminate whatever gem you are trying to use that requires this gem (e.g. ruby-debug)

For more information, [look at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5754493/ruby-on-rails-linecache-error-while-trying-to-bundle-install?rq=1)