# gem install ruby-debug19 - *** extconf.rb failed ***

Tags: ruby, rvm, ruby-debug

I recently blew away and re-installed `rvm` to fix some issues.

Now, however, when I try and install `ruby-debug19` I get:

```
$ gem install ruby-debug19

... then ...

Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing ruby-debug19:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/snowcrash/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150619-25075-s8ve57.rb extconf.rb
checking for vm_core.h... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/snowcrash/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-ruby-dir
    --without-ruby-dir
    --with-ruby-include
    --without-ruby-include=${ruby-dir}/include
    --with-ruby-lib
    --without-ruby-lib=${ruby-dir}/lib
/Users/snowcrash/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/ruby_core_source-0.1.5/lib/ruby_core_source.rb:39:in `create_makefile_with_core': uninitialized constant Ruby_core_source::Config (NameError)
    from extconf.rb:19:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/snowcrash/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/linecache19-0.5.12 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/snowcrash/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.2.0-static/linecache19-0.5.12/gem_make.out
```

And the log just contains these lines.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ruby-debug19 only works on Ruby 1.9.  For Ruby 2.0 and above use [byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug).

```
gem install byebug
```